# Registration form cant enter values in database

Tags: php, mysql

This is simple registration test page which is not working i m only loading the php file here plese tell me whats wrong .

### register.inc.php

```
<?php 
// Include required MySQL configuration file and functions 
require_once('config.inc.php'); 
require_once('functions.inc.php'); 
  
// Start session 
session_start(); 

              $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE); 
  
              // Check connection 
              if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
                            printf("Unable to connect to database: %s", mysqli_connect_error()); 
                            exit();
              } 
  
  else{
              // Escape any unsafe characters before querying database 
              $username = (isset($_POST['username']));
              $password =  $mysqli->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['pass1']));
              $emaill = $mysqli->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['emaill']));             
              $fname = (isset($_POST['fname']));
              $lname = (isset($_POST['lname']));
                
              
              $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `log`.`users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$emaill', '$fname', '$lname' )";
               
               $result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
               }
        
?>
```

the result enters a blank row where all columns have value =1  and id keeps on incrementing and if you try to edit or select those values it shows that the field is null
what wrong is going on ?

Comment: You're inserting only the boolean values of whether you have received the data. Fix that and the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the values to `true` which is what `(isset($_POST['lname']))` will evaluate to.

Remove `isset()` from your variable assignments.